# App force closes with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/AsyncTask

Tags: android, webview, android-asynctask

We recently introduced OAuth login in our app. This means using a `WebView` to authenticate the user, and an `AsyncTask` to do necessary `REST` calls afterwards.

Unfortunately, after introducing this login method, we're getting reports of the app force closing. This seems to be related to other `AsyncTask`s  that are executed after the login, but the stack traces does unfortunately not tell us much:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3100)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3095)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/AsyncTask
at com.foo.bar.TransmissionActivity.transmit(TransmissionActivity.java:44)
... 14 more
```

We managed to fix the error above by using RoboAsyncTask (from RoboGuice), instead of `AsyncTask` from the Android SDK, but we have other activities that use `WebView`s. `WebView` apparently uses `AsyncTask` somewhere in its call stack, and errors similar the one shown above (`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/AsyncTask`) have started to show in our error logs.

The error happens on different devices, and different Android versions, with no apparent pattern. We have tried to reproduce the error ourselves, without any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had similar issue when I create task in wrong time and place. Could you show example of code with AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with the build setup. (Build order of src/gen has been known to cause some issues, the libs folder for the compat library being called lib has caused some issues for me on new sdk versions).

To see if it is create a new project (in eclipse, since that's 100% android official). Add a webview and an asynctask and then do a diff on the project with your project. Ignoring src/gen/res. Hopefully you'll find that the src/gen are built in the wrong order or something like that.

~ Anders